# Setting up a Wavecom M1206B-ON USB0

Tags: linux, usb, sms-gateway

This Wavecom works on the old server on ttyS0 OK, on the new Ubuntu server I am using USB0, dmesg acknowledged "pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0", but minicom does not seem to be talking to it.
What is missing? Do I need to modify the config on minicom? I do not know if I need to install a driver and could not find one on Google anyway.
Any suggestions welcome,
Tim, London

Answer (score 0):

OK, the missing components:
sudo ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 modem
also required /usr/bin/runscript
Now minicom is answering...